# IBM Worklight - firing "page change" similar event in a single HTML file

Tags: jquery, ibm-mobilefirst

Assuming of having an application with `n` pages in the same file `MyApp.html` like this

```
<div data-role="page" id="page1"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="page2"></div>
<div data-role="page" id="page3"></div>
...
<div data-role="page" id="page-n"></div>
```

how can i fire an event after i have showed one of them? If in #page1 i have an element (`<ul>` for example) which i create dynamically and i want to show a message (like "Loaded" for example) only after it was inserted into the DOM what may i use? Is correct this reasoning:

```
// first add dynamically elements
$("#page1 .mydiv .myul").append(lists);
// then change to the #page1
$.mobile.changePage("#page1");
// finally show a message when the page is loaded with the inserted elements
$("#page1").bind("pagechange",function({ // show message "Loaded" }));
```

Answer (score 4):

```
$( "#page1" ).on( "pageshow", function( event, ui ) {
     alert( "page1 is shown and this page was just hidden: " + ui.prevPage );
});
```